# Using CityData[] vs. Entity for population

Tags: curated-data, geographics, entity

I am using v12.2.0-Win7-x64.

```
CityData[Entity[
  "City", {"Shanghai", "Shanghai", "China"}], "Population"]
```

> Quantity[14007000, "People"]

```
Entity["City", {"Shanghai", "Shanghai", "China"}]["Population"]
```

> Quantity[24152700, "People"]

---

[image]

**Question**

Am I using these correctly? Why is there (such) a difference? Thanks for your help as always.

Comment: Spot checking a few cities, I'm seeing that EntityValue consistently gives a higher population than CityData. Maybe CityData adheres strictly to some sort of city boundary and EntityValue corresponds to a more informal concept of "city" that extends to surrounding areas?

Comment: `AdministrativeDivisionData[{"Shanghai", "China"}, "Population"]` gives about 23 million, which is closer to but still less than `EntityValue[Entity["City", {"Shanghai", "Shanghai", "China"}], "Population"]`

Comment: For `Entity["City", {"Shanghai", "Shanghai", "China"}]`, I searched if there were "Metro Area" / "Suburban" population properties etc. but that attempt was not successful.

Comment: "PopulationDensity" is the same for both methods. That seems weird given that total population differs.

Comment: I sort of expected for someone with expertise in the Entity system to weigh in here. Since no one has, does it seem worth reporting the issue to Wolfram?

Comment: @lericr Thanks for your effort and time. I will wait a few days before moving on.

Comment: Thanks to @BobHanlon for the answer. One update per decade seems rather slow for population data. I am also going to add the curated data tag to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**THIS IS AN EXTENDED COMMENT**

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

With[{city = Entity["City", {"Shanghai", "Shanghai", "China"}]},
 Column@{
   CityData[city, "Population"],
   city["Population"],
   city[EntityProperty["City", "Population"]]}]
```

[image]

The different data values appear to represent data for different dates.

```
(pop = Table[{yr, 
     Entity["City", {"Shanghai", "Shanghai", "China"}][
      Dated["Population", yr]]}, {yr, 2000, 2021}]) // Grid
```

[image]

The older data appears to be either interpolated or extrapolated. Newer data appears only to be occasionally updated.

Comment: Excellent! I wasn't familiar with Dated. I have previously had vague misgivings about entity properties without dates, but don't use entities enough to have stumbled on Dated. Thanks!