# Update of Energy Data in the Wolfram Data Base

Tags: data

The other day I was looking up the energy consumption of some countries through Wolfram Alpha and found very nice results, but they were from 2012... Is there a prospect of getting more recent data on energy consumption of countries? More general, is the data on Wolfram Alpha updated with some structure or mostly from a voluntairy point of view?

Kind regards

Comment: See my recent post about [population](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/274042/using-citydata-vs-entity-for-population) data. Please include code showing how you are calculating some of these numbers. Thanks.